# Migrating dedicated server and changing name server IP address

Tags: linux, dedicated-server

I want to transfer my dedicated server to another service provider/host and I want to ask about the name server IP address changes.
My old nameservers are ns1.mydomain.com , ns2.mydomain.com and 
the new servers will also be called ns1.mydomain.com, ns2.mydomain.com, only the ip address will be changed.

Will my domain registrar will update it automatically? Which server of them will be?
To put the the question in another way, how can I point to the new server ip address although the nameserver will be the in same domain?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [article](http://support.simpledns.com/kb/a89/moving-a-dns-server-to-a-new-ip-address.aspx) explains it perfectly:

> If you are keeping the DNS server name (typically "ns#.domain.com")
>   and just moving it to a new IP address, then you only need to change
>   the DNS server registration (ns#.domain.com = IP) with your registrar
>   and change your own A-record for the server name. Changing the DNS
>   server registration is often a "hidden" function with the registrar.
>   For example with Network Solutions you login to your account, and then
>   use the "Manage Host Servers" function. Other registrars may call this
>   something else - or don't even have an online function for this and
>   instead require you to e-mail them about this.

**The answers to your questions are:**

1. No, the registrar is not going to 'catch' it automatically.
2. You need to change the old dns server ip addresses (with new ones) with your domain registrar. Once it is updated you can continue editing zone files at new servers.
3. The way you can do it may vary. May be you will be able to do it from within your control panel or you have to contact technical support.